# Testing a webtable with nested Ng-Repeat (Protractor)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

Here is the web-table that I am trying to validate.I am having difficulty in constructing a method that can work on table with nested ng-repeat.
So, for example I have to extract data from match column. So this, table is constructed  in such way that there is a ng-repeat for row and then ng-repeat for column. So inside 1 row there can be multiple ng-repeat(for a particular column). Please let me know how can create a method to validate this table.

```
<div class="data">
<table class="table table-striped table-hover ng-scope">
<tbody>
    <!-- ngRepeat: row in table.filtered track by table.idPropertyFn(row) -->
    <tr ng-repeat-start="row in table.filtered track by table.idPropertyFn(row)" ng-class="table.getRowClasses(table.idPropertyFn(row), $index+1)" id="3-1-row" class="ng-scope odd">
        <td class="column-checkbox">
            <label>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-model="table.selectedItemsBooleanMap[table.idPropertyFn(row)]" ng-change="table.toggleSelected(row)" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-empty">
            <span class="label"></span>
            </label>
        </td>
        <td row-property="order" default-sort="" header-name="rules.rulesList.colName.order" ng-switch="rulesLocked" ng-class="{ruleDisabled:row.disabled, rulePending:row.isRuleStartDatePending, ruleExpired:row.isRuleEndDateExpired}" class="rules-column order-column">
            <!-- ngSwitchWhen: false -->
            <div ng-switch-when="false" class="row ng-scope">
                <div class="col-xs-9"><input type="number" size="4" ng-model="row.order" min="1" max="5000" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]+$/" ng-blur="updateOrderOnBlur(row)" class="orderField ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-valid-min ng-valid-max ng-valid-pattern"></div>
                <!-- ngIf: rules.length > 1 -->
            </div>
            <!-- end ngSwitchWhen: --><!-- ngSwitchDefault: -->
        </td>
        <td row-property="name" header-name="rules.rulesList.colName.name" ng-class="{ruleDisabled:row.disabled, rulePending:row.isRuleStartDatePending, ruleExpired:row.isRuleEndDateExpired}" class="rules-column name-column">
            <!-- ngIf: row.disabled --><!-- ngIf: row.isRuleStartDatePending && !row.disabled --><!-- ngIf: row.isRuleEndDateExpired && !row.disabled --><span akam-text-overflow="row.name" class="akam-text-overflow-wrapper ng-binding ng-isolate-scope">test1</span>
        </td>
        <td row-property="matchesStr" header-name="rules.rulesList.colName.match" ng-class="{ruleDisabled:row.disabled, rulePending:row.isRuleStartDatePending, ruleExpired:row.isRuleEndDateExpired}" class="rules-column match-column">
            <span all-matches="" row="row" class="ng-isolate-scope">
                <div class="allMatches">
                    <!-- ngIf: !row.matches --><!-- ngRepeat: match in row.matches -->
                    <div ng-repeat="match in row.matches" class="match ng-scope">
                        <b translate="" class="ng-scope ng-binding">Protocol</b>
                        <span rule-list-match-op="" match="match" class="ng-isolate-scope">
                            <!-- ngIf: displayMatchOp -->
                            <span ng-if="displayMatchOp" class="ng-scope">
                                &nbsp;<span translate="" class="ng-scope ng-binding">is one of</span><!-- ngIf: caseSensitive --><!-- ngIf: wildcards -->
                            </span>
                            <!-- end ngIf: displayMatchOp --><!-- ngIf: isRange -->
                        </span>
                        <ul match="match" order="row.order" class="rules-column-ul ng-scope ng-isolate-scope" rule-list-matches-protocol="" rule-list-matches-factory="rule-list-matches-protocol">
                            <!-- ngRepeat: value in values -->
                            <li ng-repeat="value in values" class="ng-scope"><span akam-text-overflow="value" class="akam-text-overflow-wrapper match-col-value ng-binding ng-isolate-scope">http</span></li>
                            <!-- end ngRepeat: value in values -->
                        </ul>
                        <!-- ngIf: showClientIP(match) -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- end ngRepeat: match in row.matches -->
                    <div ng-repeat="match in row.matches" class="match ng-scope">
                        <b translate="" class="ng-scope ng-binding">Cookie</b>
                        <span rule-list-match-op="" match="match" class="ng-isolate-scope">
                            <!-- ngIf: displayMatchOp -->
                            <span ng-if="displayMatchOp" class="ng-scope">
                                &nbsp;<span translate="" class="ng-scope ng-binding">is one of</span><!-- ngIf: caseSensitive --><!-- ngIf: wildcards -->
                            </span>
                            <!-- end ngIf: displayMatchOp --><!-- ngIf: isRange -->
                        </span>
                        <ul match="match" order="row.order" class="rules-column-ul ng-scope ng-isolate-scope" rule-list-matches-cookie="" rule-list-matches-factory="rule-list-matches-cookie">
                            <!-- ngIf: values.length == 0 --><!-- ngRepeat: value in values --><!-- ngIf: values.length != 0 -->
                            <li ng-repeat="value in values" ng-if="values.length != 0" class="ng-binding ng-scope">test=123</li>
                            <!-- end ngIf: values.length != 0 --><!-- end ngRepeat: value in values -->
                        </ul>
                        <!-- ngIf: showClientIP(match) -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- end ngRepeat: match in row.matches -->
                </div>
            </span>
        </td>
```

EDIT: Here is the code that I was using.The problem in this method is that it doesn't take care of a column when it has multiple ng-repeat.

```
validateMatchRuleTable: function() {
    element.all(by.repeater(versionLocators.constants.selectAllRowsFromTable_repeater)).then(function(numOfRows){
        for (var i = 0; i <numOfRows.length; i++) {
            var rows = element.all(by.repeater(versionLocators.constants.selectAllRowsFromTable_repeater).row(i));
            var cellTexts = rows.map(function (elm) {
                return {
                    name: elm.element(by.binding(versionLocators.constants.matchRuleNameColumn_css)).getText().then(function (text) {
                        return text;
                    }),
               });
          }
     });
},
```

Here in the above method I want to return one more column named match which has ng-repeat(match in row.matches). How can I return all the data inside this in the same method I am using. Sorry for a long post.

Comment: Can you give more info about what you want to find and how you want to approach it? 


You can use [by.repeater](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.repeater) and pick a row and then chain a new `repeater` for the `row.matches` like 
`element(by.repeater('table.filtered track by table.idPropertyFn(row)').row(X)).element(by.repeater('match in row.matches').row(x))`


Or make a more smarter method to `filter` through you table based on a 'needle' with [filter()](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter)

Comment: Edited my question

Answer (score 0):

Using element.all().each() method, we can develop a method which look at row wise and column wise value. Follow the below code:

```
element.all(by.repeater="match in row.matches").each(function(row,rIndex){
 //do reapet action on earch row of a table 
  row.all(by.repeater="value in values").each(function(col,cIndex){
 //get the each column text value
   col.getText().then(functioncValue{
    console.log("Row Index -"+rIndex+"\n Column Index -"+
                           cIndex+"\n Col valu is-"+cValue);
   });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  it('verify webTable', function(){


    element.all(by.tagName("tr")).then(function(rows){
        console.log("rowcount:" + rows.length);

        for(let i = 0; i<rows.length;i++){

            rows[i].$$('td').then(function(cols){

                //let cells = rows[i].$$('td');
                for(let j =0; j<cols.length; j++){


                        cols[j].getAttribute("innerText").then(function(txt){
                           // Here you can add a condition to match your expected and actual values
                           console.log('Values:' + txt);

                        });

                }
            });

        }

    });
```

Comment: Could you please explain more details about your code?